# Passing multiple rows from gridview in form1 to form2 and wait for a button click

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have this code that have passing multiple rows from gridview in form1"FrmPaint" to form2 "OptionsPaint" after making some changes passing this data to gridview2 in form1"FrmPaint"

```
OptionsPaint OPaint = new OptionsPaint();        
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow rowGridView1 = (gridView1.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as DataRowView).Row;
            if (OPaint == null || OPaint.IsDisposed)
            OPaint = new OptionsPaint();
            OPaint.Show();

            OPaint.bsRepere.Text = rowGridView1["BS"].ToString() + " " + "Repère: " + rowGridView1["Repère"].ToString();
            OPaint.quantity.EditValue = rowGridView1["Reste Qté"];

            OPaint.OK.Click += (sender1, e1) =>
             {
                 DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                 row[0] = rowGridView1["BS"];
                 row[1] = rowGridView1["Repère"];
                 row[2] = rowGridView1["Profil"];
                 row[3] = OPaint.quantity.EditValue;
                 dt.Rows.Add(row);
               OPaint.Close();
            }; 
         }
     }
```

when I select only one row the code work fine,but when I select multiple rows 
the form2"OptionsPaint" show only one time with the last value selectd in gridview from from1 .is there a way to stop the code until the user click a button and then complete the rest of the code . 
[image]

Comment: It is almost trivial to use a DataView where a bool column in the underlying datatable controls which form/DGV a row should display in

Comment: I used to use this code with layoutcontrol and works well with single and multiple rows,but when I use form (form2)they didn't work for multiple rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the equivalent of what your code does:

```
//imagine it is a form with a single label and a button
OptionsForm of = new OptionsForm();

string[] sa = new string[]{ "a","b","c" };

foreach(string s in sa){
  of.Show();
  of.MyLabel.Text = s;
  of.MyButton.Click += (some event handler);
}
```

If you have 3 strings, this code loop will run completely 3 times: the first time it runs, if the `OptionsForm of` is not showing it will show. Repeatedly calling Show() on a form that is already visible, does nothing.

Then over the next few milliseconds the label text will be updated 3 times (so fast you won't event see it, especially as while your code is running no window messages are processed) and will finally be set to "c" - you'll never see "a" or "b". Your button click event will have 3 handlers attached to it. I'm not entirely sure if this is helpful or not, though I suspect not, as in your case it will put X rows into dt that are identical.

This is why when you select multiple rows only the last one shows; each loop passing overwrites the previous and nothing stops the loop running to completion in milliseconds

So what to do about it?

If you want this form to appear once for every selected item, so if the user selected 10 items then this form will appear 10 times in a row and they have to click 10 times to get rid of it then move the OPaint.Show() to AFTER you attach the button click event handler and make it ShowDialog instead of Show:

```
var dResult = OPaint.ShowDialog();
```

There is some additional setup you need to do to use a form as a dialog, because you need to declare which button is the OK and which is the Cancel. See this example from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?view=netframework-4.7.2 - set the .dialogresult of your ok/cancel buttons and tell the form which is accept/cancel. Remove the instruction to Close() from the button click handler- buttons that control dialog type forms cause the form to close automatically when they're clicked

You'll need an if to test the dResult to know if the user clicked OK or Cancel, and handle accordingly - I don't know what you'll do if they click cancel?

Calling ShowDialog will cause the code to stop at that point until the user decides, like a messagebox does

Finally, I just want to point out that user interfaces that do this are incredibly annoying. You should consider having just one dialog that asks "ok to update all these 10 rows?" or perhaps having a single form that can show and update multiple things at once

Comment: @aius Jard ,thank you very much for your help ,about showing one dialog each row has his properties(Quantity, Paint Type) must be set individually