# Referencing a UserControl that contains a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am experimenting with placing usercontrols in a Panel and cannot find out how to reference the objects in the usercontrol form

For Example.

I have two panels on my "mainForm" Panel1 is on the left and contains menu buttons, Panel2 is on the right and is where I will display the selected Usercontrol form.

I created a USerControl Form Called UCreportResults.vb  that form has a DGV that displays data from a SQL query.

I loaded the UC into a panel on my MainForm like so:

```
Dim Uc2 As New UCreportResults
Me.Panel2.Controls.Add(Uc2)
```

now I want to reference a DGV that is on the UCreportResults form that I loaded.

this is where I am a little lost.

I keep thinking its something like this?

```
me.panel2.controls.?
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Try exposing the grid's data source (List<Class>, DataTable, etc) as a property of the UserControl.

Comment: In the UC, create a read-only property that returns the DGV. Then you can access it in the Form like: `Me.panel2.Controls.OfType(Of UCreportResults).First.DGV`. Where DGV is the name of the suggested property.

Comment: @dr.null curious that you'd advocate a coding style whereby a class exposes its internals so that other classes can fiddle with them directly.. ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Hello There, sorry for the delay. Well, a class exposes its members in away or another no matter what. Not recommended design, you are right. Just a shortcut. Sometimes you need to do it this way if you need to do much with a control. Shadowing many properties / methods of a control seems also not a good nor practical approach. Good point, thank you.

Comment: @CaiusJard You [do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993682/14171304) advocate that already :)